# How to add common Tittle, label and legend in Matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, title, subplot

My following code can't add a common title, common legend also a common x and y label. When I add title, legend in between the `for loop` it works but its not working for the whole figure?
I want to add a common title, common legend, and shared x and y label in this plot. What is the best way to do that?
[image: plot]

**My code**

```
#position vs Time 
h = 0.05
nrow, ncol, count = 2,4,1


plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.title("Common Title") #does not working
with plt.style.context('ggplot'):
    for inv in range(8):
        plt.subplot(nrow, ncol, count)
        x = [1]
        v = [0]

        rk4_x = [1] #position
        rk4_v = [0] #velocity

        t = np.arange(0, 30, 0.1)
        for i in range(len(t)-1):
            k1 = h*v[i]
            l1 = h*-(x[i])
            k2 = h*(v[i]+l1)
            l2 = h*-(x[i]+k1)
            x_value = x[i]+0.5*(k1+k2)
            x.append(x_value)
            v_value = v[i]+0.5*(l1+l2)
            v.append(v_value)

            k1 = h*rk4_v[i]
            l1 = h*-(rk4_x[i])
            k2 = h*(rk4_v[i]+0.5*l1)
            l2 = h*-(rk4_x[i]+0.5*k1)
            k3 = h*(rk4_v[i]+0.5*l2)
            l3 = h*-(rk4_x[i]+0.5*k2)
            k4 = h*(rk4_v[i]+l3)
            l4 = h*-(rk4_x[i]+k3)
            x_value = rk4_x[i]+(1/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
            rk4_x.append(x_value)
            v_value = rk4_v[i]+(1/6)*(l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)
            rk4_v.append(v_value)

            

        # with plt.style.context('ggplot'):
        # plt.figure()
        plt.plot(t, x,'r', label= "Position vs Time RK2")
        plt.plot(t, rk4_x, 'k--',  label = "Position vs Time RK4")

        plt.ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
        h = round(h,3)
        plt.title("h="+str(h), fontsize= '11')
        plt.grid('on')
        plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', which='both', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Position')
        plt.legend()


        h = h + 0.05
        count = count+1
```

Comment: Try to use `plt.suptitle('common title')`, See [matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html)

Comment: it worked. Can you help about `plt.subxlabel('common x label')` not working. Showing plt don't have any module named this. @BG Park

Comment: Use suptitle for both, Change the `y=` parameter. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html

Comment: @TahmidulAzomSany Please see the answer below. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use subplots with fig, axs. See [the document on matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

And you should use **Numpy array** not the python list to speed up the numerical calculation. (Not this example, but generally).

Also, If the amount of calculation increases, it seems necessary to make the formula simple. Like `x[i+1] = (1 - 0.5 * h**2) * x[i]+ h * v[i]`

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Agg')
plt.style.use('ggplot')

def get_x_v(h, t):
    x = np.ones_like(t)
    v = np.zeros_like(t)
    rk4_x = np.ones_like(t)
    rk4_v = np.zeros_like(t)

    for i, _ in enumerate(t[:-1]):
        k1 = h * (v[i])
        l1 = h * (x[i]) * -1
        k2 = h * (v[i] + l1)
        l2 = h * (x[i] + k1) * -1

        x[i+1] = x[i] + 0.5 * (k1 + k2)
        v[i+1] = v[i] + 0.5 * (l1 + l2)

        rk1 = h * (rk4_v[i])
        rl1 = h * (rk4_x[i]) * -1
        rk2 = h * (rk4_v[i] + 0.5 * rl1)
        rl2 = h * (rk4_x[i] + 0.5 * rk1) * -1
        rk3 = h * (rk4_v[i] + 0.5 * rl2)
        rl3 = h * (rk4_x[i] + 0.5 * rk2) * -1
        rk4 = h * (rk4_v[i] + rl3)
        rl4 = h * (rk4_x[i] + rk3) * -1

        rk4_x[i+1] = rk4_x[i]+(1/6)*(rk1+2*rk2+2*rk3+rk4)
        rk4_v[i+1] = rk4_v[i]+(1/6)*(rl1+2*rl2+2*rl3+rl4)

    return x, v, rk4_x, rk4_v

h = 0.05
ncol, nrow = 4, 2

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrow, ncols=ncol, figsize=(20, 10))
fig.suptitle('Common Title', y=0.94, fontsize=20)
fig.supxlabel('Common X Label', y=0.05, fontsize=14)

t = np.arange(0, 30, 0.1)
for ax in axs.flat:
    x, v, rk4_x, rk_v = get_x_v(h, t)
    ax.plot(t, x, 'r', label="Position vs Time RK2")
    ax.plot(t, rk4_x, 'k--',  label="Position vs Time RK4")

    ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
    ax.set_title('h={0}'.format(str(round(h,3))), fontsize='11')
    ax.grid('on')
    ax.tick_params(labelcolor='none', which='both',
                    top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Position')
    ax.legend(loc=1)
    ax.set_facecolor('gray')
    h += 0.05

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]